# ERROR: Could not build wheels for neuralcoref, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy, coreference-resolution

I am running spacy 3.6.1 on google colab. After all requirements installation, I got an error when I tried to install tokenizer

I am trying to use NeuralCoref4.0 to perform coreference resolution on google colab. I am running spacy 3.6.1 and python 3.10.12. However, I got an error when I tried to install neuralcoref. The NeuralCoref documentation say its compatible with spacy 2.1+ and python 3.6+ [neuralcoref github](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref)

I used the command `!pip install neuralcoref` to install, but I'm getting an error;

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for neuralcoref, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

[error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73XhR.png)

Does anyone have the solution for my problem, either a way to install neuralcoref on google colab or a simple approach to do coreference resolution without it. Thanks for your help.

I expected NeuralCoref to install correctly on google colab, so that it can be used for coreference resolution.

Answer (score 0):

`requirement.txt` clearly mentions that **`spacy version < 3.0.0`**

Your spacy version is `spacy 3.6.1`.

Please downgrade your spacy version by:

```
pip install spacy==2.1.0
```

https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/blob/master/requirements.txt

[image]